# How to process a JSON payload with drop wizard?

Tags: java, json, jersey, dropwizard

I have a simple class called `Thing`

```
public class Thing {
  private int id
  private String name
  //getters, setters, constructor
}
```

I would like to send a request with a payload and process it.

The request would look something like this:

```
curl -i -d '{"thing": {"id": 11, "name": "foobar"}}' http://localhost:8080/thing/{username}
```

But I can't figure out how to process the json request. This is what my method looks like:

```
@Path("/thing/{username}")
@POST
public Thing add(@PathParam("username") String username) {
  //how can I process the JSON payload sent and convert it to Thing object?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Thing impl = mapper.readValue(username, Thing.class);
```

As long as `username` is valid JSON and maps to `Thing`, this should work.

Note: You may have to annotate the class members or methods of `Thing`. For example in my case I had to manage circular references using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference`. But you can read up about this and other annotations in the API documentation.